# Replace if/else statement with pattern

Tags: c#, if-statement, design-patterns

In the code below, I'm trying to determine what the business date should be depending on if the month to date (mtd) indicator is true or if the previous 2 business date (btd) indicator is true.

Currently, if I come up with another indicator then I'll have to include another else if statement.

I've read that the approach to make this code easier to maintain is to use the Factory Design pattern.  However, I'm not sure what steps to take in order to implement the pattern.

Here is the code:

```
    public static string GetBusDate(bool mtdIndicator, bool prev2BusDtInd)
    {
        string busDate = Helper.PreviousBusinessDate;

        if (mtdIndicator)
        {
            busDate = Helper.FOMBusDt;
        }
        else if (prev2BusDtInd)
        {
            busDate = Helper.Previous2BusinessDate;
        }

        return busDate;
    }
```

Comment: _I'm not sure what steps to take in order to implement the pattern.._ First make a proper research on what factory patterns are...

Comment: I'd just use a nested conditional operator at this point. I'm not sure there's any need for a specific design pattern - and factory patterns don't seem to be relevant.

Comment: The factory pattern would work if the format doesn't change during the lifetime of the object. If that can be the case, you'd use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). But in this simple case, I'd stick to an `if`/`else if` chain

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you need from looking at a single function. It's unclear where your parameters are coming from, and what you're doing with the result. Factory is just a way of instantating objects which have a common interface, i.e. hiding the concrete implementation from the caller. You are probably looking for how to "replace conditional with polymorphism", and then once you do that you can use a factory to instantiate concrete implementations.

Comment: I have no idea what these parameters represent and what your helpers return. Basically i have no idea what you are doing there. So i can't help to improve it.

Comment: I would say; don't try to find a solution for a problem that doesn't exist. Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry for the vague question.  I was over complicating it.  I tried looking into the factory pattern before asking the question, but found it complicated to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Factory Pattern (Factory Method && Abstract Factory) is not going to work well for your use case, because this pattern will only force you to create a couple of classes for each if statement and the pattern usually returns an abstract object to your client code to consume (not your case because you're returning a simple string).

You also can't use a Simple Factory (which is not a design pattern) because will only move the conditional logic into a single class, so your code design will not improve.

You should **not** use a design pattern just increase the complexity of your code without the benefits of flexibility.

For your use case I would simply leave it as an if/else statement using a  single line of code.

```
return mtdIndicator ? Helper.FOMBusDt :
       prev2BusDtInd ? Helper.Previous2BusinessDate : 
                       Helper.PreviousBusinessDate;
```

If you want to replace conditionals with polymorphism you should try:

- Chain-of-Responsibility Pattern
- Strategy Pattern
- Decorator Pattern

... or other patterns (depends on the overall architecture)

Also you can avoid ifs by following 'Tell DON'T Ask'.

- You should send a request to your low level component to do task X
- You should NOT ask a low level component about it's internal
  context / state (you do that by avoiding functions like `isStateXOk():Boolean`)

TIP: Don't avoid a short if/else statement by creating from 3 to 10+ classes, **avoid** a switch by making classes for each case branch.